# Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/agents' when running create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create a new react application.
I have node version 14.15.3 and npm version 6.14

```
Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/agents'
```

when running `npx create-react-app`

[issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woiod.png)

Comment: `npm update @babel/preset-env` try with this command

Comment: `npm install next@canary` and also with this command

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? The command in the first comment worked for me.

Comment: @DulangaHeshan Worked for me. Maybe this should be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 64):

I ran into this issue while working on a Vue project and I fixed it by installing the `caniuse-lite` package again.

Just run `npm i caniuse-lite` in your terminal.

Then spin up your app again after the installation.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is necessary?

Answer (score 5):

```
npm update @babel/preset-env
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem earlier. I installed a previous version of caniuse-lite `npm i caniuse-lite@1.0.30001281` worked for Next-js app.

Comment: Just ran into this on a fresh NextJS project, and this suggestion worked for me. But there must be something wrong to cause this.

Comment: Yes, so bad. what is going on?

Comment: caniuse-lite 1.0.30001394 delete the css-unicode-bidi.js file. Temporary solution: install caniuse-lite@1.0.30001393

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar issue:  `npm i caniuse-lite` fixed it.

> error: index.js: Cannot find module '../lib/supported' Require stack:
>
> - ..\node_modules\caniuse-lite\dist\unpacker\feature.js
> - ..\node_modules\browserslist\node.js